# How to convert Rebase syncState back to Firebase

Tags: firebase, rebase

I was using `Rebase` [syncState](https://github.com/tylermcginnis/re-base#syncstateendpoint-options) but now I don't wanna use it. How can I use normal firebase code equivalent to this code?

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.ref = base.syncState('' + this.props.match.params.locationsId + '/app', {
            context: this,
            state: 'locations'
    });
}
```

Comment: I might be able to answer this question later today. In the meanwhile checkout the "watchGuestAddedEvent" method of this tutorial https://www.codementor.io/vijayst/using-firebase-with-redux-for-building-a-react-app-du1086puw